# How to query a sub document that is less than a particular size in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a game object that has a boolean `isOpen` and a sub document `players`that is an array of players. I'd like to find a game that is open for players to join that contains less than 5 players. How do I do this? Preferably without using `$where`

```
//made up sample for reference  
const sampleDocument = {
    isOpen: true,
    isOver: false,
    players : [{
        socketID: 'sldfjskdfjsjdfsdfj',
        isBot: false,
        name: 'NickName',
    }],
    startTime: 32343234
```

**The relevant line of code**

```
let game = await Game.findOne({isOpen: true, /*players : { $size: {$lt: 5} }*/})
```

Comment: Can you show the sample document?

Comment: With the posted sample document, `players` is not an array field - its a sub-document only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/).

```
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $and: [
      {
        $eq: [
          "$isOpen",
          true
        ],
        
      },
      {
        $lt: [
          {
            "$size": "$players"
          },
          5
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

Comment: @Young Shun i'm using mongoose not mongodb. Just to be sure the query i specify doesn't matter right?

Comment: [*When executing a query with a callback function, you specify your query as a JSON document. The JSON document's syntax is the same as the MongoDB shell.*](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html#executing) You can pass the query to Mongoose